# Removing from a list through collision

Tags: python, arrays, list, pygame

How would I make it so in the game, the blue block is removed after it is hit three times instead of one?

When the blue block is removed, here is the code that makes it happen.

```
    #for blue (easy) blocks
    for block in easy_blocks:
        if block.colliderect(ball):
            speed[1] = -speed[1]
            easy_blocks.remove(block)
```

I'm assuming that a list has to be made, and when a block is hit, a value in that list goes up by one, when the list index's # reaches 3 then it is removed. Not sure though.

Here is the full code of the game.

```
#December 16, 2019
#Final Project - Breakout

#IMPORTING LIBRARIES-----
import pygame
import sys
import time

#INITIALIZING SCREEN SIZE-----
pygame.init()
screen_size = (597, 700)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_size),0)
pygame.display.set_caption("BREAKOUT")

#retrieve screen measurements
screen_w = screen.get_width()
screen_h = screen.get_height()

#retrieve position of center of screen
center_x = int(screen_w/2)
center_y = int(screen_h/2)

#COLOURS-----
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
PURPLE = (154, 136, 180)

#BACKGROUND-----
screen.fill(BLACK)
pygame.display.update()


#PICTURES-----
background_image = pygame.image.load("space_background.png")
easy_block_image = pygame.image.load("easy_block.png")
paddle_image = pygame.image.load("paddle.png")
ball_image = pygame.image.load("ball.png")

#SPEED-----
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60 #set frames per second
speed = [4,4]
paddle_speed = 6

#VARIABLES-----

#paddle
paddle_x = center_x
paddle_y = 600
paddle_w = 78
paddle_h = 10

paddle_dx = 0
paddle_dy = 0

#ball
ball_x = center_x
ball_y = center_y
ball_w = 12
ball_h = 12

#blocks
block_x = 5
block_w = 40
block_h = 10

#severity block positions
easy_block_y = 172
medium_block_y = 148
hard_block_y = 124
metal_block_y = 100

#severity block hits
easy_block_hits = 0

#lives displayed
lives_displayed_h = 10
lives_displayed_x = 4
lives_displayed_y = screen_h - (lives_displayed_h + 5)
lives_displayed_w = 79

#title
title_x = 5
title_y = 5
title_w = 240
title_h = 50

#test rect
rx = 0
ry = 700
rw = 700
rh = 1

#RECTS-----
paddle = pygame.Rect(paddle_x, paddle_y, paddle_w, paddle_h)
ball = pygame.Rect(ball_x, ball_y, ball_w, ball_h)
title = pygame.Rect(title_x, title_y, title_w, title_h)
lives_displayed_rect = pygame.Rect(lives_displayed_x,lives_displayed_y,lives_displayed_w,lives_displayed_h)
testrect = pygame.Rect(rx, ry, rw, rh)

#ARRAYS-----

#empty array to store rects for each block row of level
easy_blocks = []

#layout of blocks for each level
easy_block_array = [
"B B B B B B B B B B B B B B",
"B B B B B B B B B B B B B B",
]


#read the array and create the appropriate Rects FOR EACH LEVEL, store them in the walls array
for row in easy_block_array: #easy/blue
    for col in row:
        if col == "B":
            easy_block_rect = pygame.Rect(block_x, easy_block_y, block_w, block_h)
            easy_blocks.append(easy_block_rect)
        block_x += 21
    easy_block_y += 12
    block_x = 5


#LOOPS-----
intro_screen = False
game_screen = False
end_screen = False

#----------INTRO_SCREEN LOOP----------

#----------GAME_SCREEN LOOP----------
game = True
while game:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type ==pygame.QUIT:
            game = False
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        #moving paddle with keys
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                paddle_dx = -paddle_speed
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                paddle_dx = paddle_speed

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        paddle_dx = 0

    #constrain this loop to the specified FPS
    clock.tick(FPS)

    #PADDLE EVENTS-----

    #store old paddle positions
    old_paddle_x = paddle.x
    old_paddle_y = paddle.y

    #moving the paddle rect
    paddle.move_ip(paddle_dx, paddle_dy)

    #check to see if rect has left screen
    if paddle.left < 0 or paddle.right > screen_w:
        paddle.x = old_paddle_x

    #BALL EVENTS-----

    #moving ball
    ball = ball.move(speed)

    #collision bounce left & right
    if ball.left < 0 or ball.right > screen_w:
        speed[0] = -speed[0]

    #collision bounce top & bottom
    if ball.top < 0 or ball.bottom > screen_h:
        speed[1] = -speed[1]

    #collision of ball with paddle
    if paddle.colliderect(ball):
        speed[1] = -speed[1]

    #BLOCKS EVENTS-----

    #for blue (easy) blocks
    for block in easy_blocks:
        if block.colliderect(ball):
            speed[1] = -speed[1]
            easy_blocks.remove(block)

    #DRAWING/CREATING OBJECTS-----

    #removes screen trail
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    screen.blit(background_image, [0, 0])

    #drawing paddle/ball inside rect
    screen.blit(paddle_image, paddle)
    screen.blit(ball_image, ball)
    #screen.blit(title_image, title)

    #draws a block for each "B"
    for block in easy_blocks:
        screen.blit(easy_block_image, block)

    #----------END_SCREEN LOOP----------

    #updating the screen
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Make block objects that can have their own life value as well as handle their own drawing, there wont be many good solutions whilst you just have a list of rects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of appending the blocks to the list, append a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), which contains the location (rectangle) and the "strength" of the block:

```py
for row in easy_block_array: #easy/blue
    for col in row:
        if col == "B":
            easy_block_rect = pygame.Rect(block_x, easy_block_y, block_w, block_h)
            easy_blocks.append({"rect": easy_block_rect, "strength": 3})
        block_x += 21
    easy_block_y += 12
    block_x = 5
```

When a block is hit, the decrement its strength. It he strength is 0, then remove the block from the list:

```py
#for blue (easy) blocks
for block in easy_blocks:
    if block["rect"].colliderect(ball):
        speed[1] = -speed[1]
        block["strength"] -= 1
        if block["strength"] <= 0:
            easy_blocks.remove(block)
```

Drawing the block has to be slightly adapted

```py
for block in easy_blocks:
    screen.blit(easy_block_image, block["rect"])
```

---

A nice effect would be to make the "hit" blocks transparent, depending on the strength.
Copy the original image and ensure that it supports per pixel alpha ([`convert_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha)):

```py
transp_image = easy_block_image.copy().convert_alpha()
```

Blending a transparent white color on the entire surface. The alpha channel of the color has to be < 255, dependent on the strength:

```py
alpha = 255 * block["strength"] // 3
color (255, 255, 255, alpha)
```

Use [`pygame.Surface.fill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) to fill the Surface, but set the special blending flag `BLEND_RGBA_MIN`. That causes, that for each pixel and channel of the texture is calculated the minimum of the pixel color and (255, 255, 255, alpha):

```py
transp_image.fill(color, special_flags = pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MIN)
```

e.g.:

```py
for block in easy_blocks:
alpha = 255 * block["strength"] // 3
if alpha < 255:
    transp_image = easy_block_image.copy().convert_alpha()
    transp_image.fill((255, 255, 255, alpha), special_flags = pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MIN)
    screen.blit(transp_image, block["rect"])
else:
    screen.blit(easy_block_image, block["rect"])
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain that last coding block that makes it transparent?

Comment: @IJH I've add an explanation to the answer.